# Problem with locales after git installation

Tags: linux, debian, apt, localization

Some days ago i tried to install git on my Debian system.
The instalation aborted and since this moment i get a locales error everytime i try do install/remove something via apt -.-

```
apt-get remove git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
git
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 75 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = "de_DE",
LANG = "de_DE@euro"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Kann LC_ALL nicht auf die Standard-Lokale einstellen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
dpkg: error processing git (--remove):
Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
git
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i tried to reconfigure locales but i get the same error... how can i fix this?

greetz

Comment: Try `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, make sure your locale is generated.

Comment: as is wrote i already tried this

Answer (score 2):

the locale warning doesn't have anything to do with the git problem.  following the instructions, you would want to try `apt-get install --reinstall git` or `aptitude reinstall git`, then try removing it again. If you have the git package in /var/cache/apt/archives, you could also try reinstalling with somehting like `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/git_....deb` (the exact filename would vary based on arch and version of git)

Comment: http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=276966 here is the output... i dont really know what to do ^^

Comment: this is saying that apt can't find the git package (anymore?).  Did you originally install this package using apt?

Comment: yeah as i said... i tried installing git via apt some days ago and then i got the error with locale the first time

Comment: does the .deb exist in /var/cache/apt/archives ? if so, try installing it with dpkg -i

Answer (score 2):

> `18 not fully installed or removed.`

You have 18 packages in an intermediate state, you should resolve that first. There's a chance that the git issue is due to that, and it's very likely that Perl's complaints about the locales are due to that. Specifically, the Perl complaint is probably due to the `locales` package being in a non-functional state that `dpkg --configure locales` (not `dpkg-reconfigure`) or `apt-get -f install` would fix.

Run `apt-get -f install`. If this doesn't fix the problem, post the error messages that `apt-get -f install` spews out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and the following fixed the locale warnings

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

change en_US.UTF-8 to whatever locale you want to use!
I'm afraid i can't help you with the git issue. :/
maybe you will be able to reinstall it after the locale is fixed (just guessing)

Comment: Here it's probably just the `locale` package not being configured that's causing the Perl warning. That's subtly different from locales not being set up properly, which `locale-gen` would fix.

Comment: Yes but i had the same warnings as described and this fixed it. I thought it would be worth the try.